# Java applet and web browsers

Tags: java, applet

i am doing a master project on how java applet works with web browsers.Can anyone give me details or any link that can be useful.How the web browser interacts with the java applet.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do a project on a technology that many (most?) people consider obsolete and dead? You might want to think about doing the project on something that is more relevant, if you have time to make another choice.

Comment: What is a 'master project'? Is this homework?

Comment: @Justin Ethier learning from old technology is good for creating new technology: especially when being skeptical about the older tech. and learn from what was good/bad. Besides, Applets are not old, they are just unpopular (*subjective-comment* Why? Because I love them).

Comment: @Justin: I currently work on an application that shall run on android and on the web. However old applets might be, I don't see any easier way of making (parts of) my code run on both platforms, and therefore not having to code everything twice. Tell me an easier way and I call applets obsolete.

Comment: You might consider writing common parts in JavaScript (or another technology with mobile support), if your architecture will allow it: http://blog.frontendforce.com/2010/05/mobile-application-development-using-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the source of Mozilla (Firefox, e.g.)
2. Read the code that integrates the JRE for applets.
3. Ask more questions when specific issues arise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple answer will be enough and it won't require reverse-engineering Mozilla.
Until recently, applets did not interact much with the browser. The browser sent only 'start', 'stop' and 'resize' events to the applet and the applet could order the browser to open new web pages. With the Java 6 update 10, there is a possibility to call Applet functions from JavaScript and to call JavaScript from an Applet, as long as they are on the same page.
The browser creates a 'sandbox' to run the applet. The sandbox limits the access rights of the applet (e.g. applet can connect to TCP ports only on the web server, cannot access files directly on the client file system, etc.). Besides these limitations, an applet is like an autonomous application running on the client box.
You can find info on applets at 'http://java.sun.com/applets/' and 'http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html'